# Is Chaincoder IDE Compatible with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ide, hyperledger-fabric

I am learning hyperledger fabric and want to use an IDE for the same.While searching about it in google, i came across Chaincoder IDE, But according to the website, its only available for Windows 10(Pro or Enterprise) and MacOs. I am working in Ubuntu 18.04 so i want to know will it work in Ubuntu or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The website is clear

There is an exe for Windows
a Zip for Macos

So no available version for Linux.
Downloading it was enough to answer your question.